# Removing outline on image map area in email client

Tags: html, css, html-email

Can anyone knows how to remove outline on image map area on email client? I'm using Outlook 2010 email client for Email template testing and facing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Everything](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/office/en-US/6c81c9da-f00a-425c-a5ea-52cea1a79562/image-maps-in-outlook-2010-word-2010) [I find](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/office/en-US/aac24b10-40ab-4510-bd5a-17ab351a4711/how-do-i-use-an-image-map-in-outlook-2010) [points to a conclusion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6c81c9da-f00a-425c-a5ea-52cea1a79562/image-maps-in-outlook-2010-word-2010?forum=outlookdev) that you should not be using image maps in outlook to begin with.

Image maps may seem to function but they are technically "[not supported](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pcreehan/2007/05/04/what-does-unsupported-mean/)".

Comment: Thanks @Serg for your answer. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Image maps dont have good support in emails.

If there is a specific requirement and you have to use it, try adding in border=0 to the image, in style and on the element itself, otherwise stay away from image maps.

Comment: Thanks @Syfer for your answer. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of code I put in my html email CSS:

```
a img{
    border:none;
    }
img{
    display:block;
    }
```

But yeah, try not to use image maps. It's messy, and then you have all image in your email. Which emails going right into the SPAM folder for many clients.